# How to display a different image when an image is clicked?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make it so that when you click on a picture, it changes to another. I tried doing this but it doesnt work-

```
class PopScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  const PopScreen({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PopScreenState createState() => _PopScreenState();
}

class _PopScreenState extends State<PopScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String currentPath = normalPaths[widget.id];
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: animalColorThemes[widget.id],
          title: Text(
            animalData[widget.id][0],
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              currentPath = activePaths[widget.id];
            });
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      currentPath,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The image is based on the integer id that gets passed into this. The problem is probably that i'm doing `normalPath[widget.id]` before returning the widget, so when it set states, it turns into the normalPath right after turning into the activaPath. How i find my around around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because everytime you rebuild your widget, you set `currentPath` to `normalPaths[widget.id]` since you set `currentPath =  normalPaths[widget.id];` in the first line in your `build` method. To fix your issue you have to move `currentPath` outside the `build` method.

```
class _PopScreenState extends State<PopScreen> {
  late String currentPath;
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    currentPath =  normalPaths[widget.id];
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: animalColorThemes[widget.id],
          title: Text(
            animalData[widget.id][0],
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              currentPath = activePaths[widget.id];
            });
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      currentPath,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah thanks! I knew why this was occuring but didn't how to fix it. Thanks again!